# How can i distinguish the XML results of two python tests (using nosetests as test runner) with the same name but with different context

Tags: python, xml, nosetests

I have a test footest.py which runs with mysql database, and the same test runs on psql database, is there a way to distinguish this difference in an XML result file between the two tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not trying to create a `base_test_class.py` with a base test class `class BaseSQLTest(unittest.TestCase)` that contains all your tests, and 2 other files `mysqltest.py` and `psqltest.py` that contains 2 inherited classes (`class MySQLTest(BaseSQLTest)` and `class PSQLTest(BaseSQLTest)`) for your MySQL and PSQL tests.

Doing this will split your tests in the resulting XML.

Comment: Just found out that i can also use --xunit-prefix
https://code.google.com/r/jsiirola-python-nose-clone/source/browse/nose/plugins/xunit.py?spec=svn9c9026ef31cf7247391fff1650770cb93209a53f&r=9c9026ef31cf7247391fff1650770cb93209a53f